# strtok like function in C++

Tags: c++

In C using strtok function we can tokenize c style string using our any delimiters list such as " ,.- ] [ ". I know from here [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c) to tokenize c++ string by whitespace, but I want to tokenize using delimiters list (" ,.- ] [ ") in c++. How Can I accomplish this?

NOTE: I Dont want to tokenize by WHITE SPACE, rather a delimiter list. Those answer gives answer to tokenize by ws. NOT using boost.

Comment: I Dont want to tokenize by WHITE SPACE, rather a delimiter list. Those answer gives answer to tokenize by ws. NOT using boost.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/1413395

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/236137/1413395